# Using xml file instead of using web.config in webApi application

Tags: xml, web-config

Can I use xml file to store application config setting instead of using web.config?
If can, where should this xml be put in WebApi project?
Xml also no need to publish like web.config. What will be the different to store app setting in xml and web.config? Thanks in advance all experts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store app settings in a separate file as mentioned here [Reading settings from separate config file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2232059/reading-settings-from-separate-config-file)

Just remember not to use .xml file extension since it can be viewed in a browser as mentioned in the above post.