# Web.config file and changing frequently

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config

I search about put large amounts of key / value in the web config and change it frequently. The result was that, frequently changing web configuration is not good.do create two `web.config` ,one for settings and the other for key/value is better? What is proposed instead?
Is there a limit to the size of the `web.config`?

Comment: Every time you change your `web.config` and save it, the app pool your web application is running in is recycled - really *not* a good idea! Put your settings that change frequently into a separate config file, or store them in the database or something

Comment: ok,when i put key/value in a separate file and have frequently change and setting in the other by not frequently change,is there any setting to not restart whole app when one webconfig change?

Comment: When `web.config` changes - the app pool restarts - there's nothing you can do about that. Period. So if you want to avoid this - **do not** constantly modify `web.config` - put those settings elsewhere

Comment: so,when i change webconfig files,setting or key/value app restart and can not set no restart!if i want no restart put in database or other.ok?

Comment: see this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2232097/1095390