# Multiple App.Config files

Tags: c#, app-config

I want to separate my app.config file. For example I want to move ServiceModel part to another config file in the same project. How can I do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You should be able to have an empty element with the `configSource` attribute set to the second file (relative to the first). See here for how to enable it [for custom sections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/398607/how-to-enable-configsource-attribute-for-custom-configuration-section-in-net).

Answer (score 3):

I found the way. I changed the  tag like this.

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors configSource="Behaviors.config">
    </behaviors>
    <services configSource="Services.config">
    </services>
    <bindings configSource="Bindings.config">
    </bindings>
    <extensions configSource="Extensions.config">
    </extensions>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

After I created the Services.config file and their I put this

```
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior" name="EntLib31ExceptionTest.Service1">
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8001/ValidationService1/" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
    <endpoint address="" 
               binding="wsHttpBinding" 
               bindingConfiguration="CustomBinding" 
               contract="EntLib31ExceptionTest.IService"    
               behaviorConfiguration="Validation"/>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
</services>
```

The same I done in Bindings, Behaviors, Extensions.config files.

And it works

Comment: @Wilson: you need to learn to highlight your code or XML lines and press the "code" button (101 010) on the editor toolbar to format them nicely - no messy "< client" hack needed, if you only remember to format those things as code

Answer (score 2):

Use something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>    
<configuration>    
    <appSettings />    
    <connectionStrings/>    
    <system.web>    
        <compilation debug="false" strict="false" explicit="true" />    
    </system.web>    
    <appSettings file="externalSettings.config"/>    
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as my knowledge goes this is sadly not possible.

What you could do is to (if we are speaking about WCF proxies) create and configure your proxy in your code. That way you do not need the *serviceModel* section.

Now just define your own custom section for the data you need and that can then be placed outside of your configuration file.